# Transfer access to Clash of Clans from a broken device

Tags: clash-of-clans

The tablet I played CoC on just died. I've tried linking a device on my wife's tablet but it either asks me for a code or it generates a code itself.

Is there a way to get the code from the device that died? Or is there another way to access my village?

Answer (score 1):

Linking coc on different devices with the coc built in method is meant for linking Google Play with Game Center. If your devices are both android or apple, you could login with the same Google Play/Game Center account that was bound to the old village and an option to load the village will be given.